# TypeError: Pessoa.showAllData() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, self

Erro: **TypeError: Pessoa.showAllData() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'**

Eu estou tendo esse problema repetidas vezes do meu código e não to conseguindo entender o por quê. Por qual motivo ele ta me pedindo o self se ele é interno? é por que estou usando set/get?

```
from datetime import date

class Pessoa:

    currentYear = date.today()
    currentYear = currentYear.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    def __init__(self, name, dateOfBirth, height):
        self.__name = name
        self.__dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
        self.__height = height


    def setName(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def setDateOfBirth(self, dateBirth):
        self.__dateOfBirth = dateBirth

    def setHeight(self, height):
        self.__height = height


    def getName(self):
        return self.__name

    def getDateOfBirth(self):
        return self.__dateOfBirth

    def getHeight(self):
        return self.__height


    def showAllData(self):
        return print(f"Dados da Pessoa:\nNome: {self.__name}\nData de Nascimento: {self.__dateOfBirth}\nAltura: {self.__height}")

#   def ageCalculator(self, ):

pessoa1 = Pessoa("Jolie", "16/10/1998", 1.59)
Pessoa.showAllData()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está chamando o método `showAllData` através da **classe** `Pessoa`, mas o que você provavelmente queria fazer é chamá-lo pela **instância** `pessoa1`.

Mudando o código da última linha, temos o output:

```
print(pessoa1.showAllData())

# output:
# Dados da Pessoa:
# Nome: Jolie
# Data de Nascimento: 16/10/1998
# Altura: 1.59
```

O Python até permite usar a classe para chamar um método, mas nesse caso você precisa providenciar a instância manualmente - experimente com:

```
print(Pessoa.showAllData(pessoa1))

# mesmo output
```

Comment: Caramba! é verdade. Obrigado, amigo.